# Ajax upload file to php using lighttpd

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, lighttpd

I have this script javascript:

```
function submitCID(){
    var file_data = $('#cidLoader').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('cidLoader', file_data);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/uploadCid.php",
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,    
        success: function(){
            alert("ok");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

to upload a .cid file (like xml).

PHP code is:

```
<?php
    $filename = $_FILES["cidLoader"]["name"];

    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["cidLoader"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["cidLoader"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["cidLoader"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["cidLoader"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
?>
```

And HTML form is like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="fileInfo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="cidLoader" name="cidLoader" type="file" accept=".cid,.CID" />
</form>
```

Unfortunelly I get error: *Undefined index: cidLoader*

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES)`, and see what arrived at the server.

Comment: I get array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}

Comment: what does alert(errorThrown) show ?

Comment: nothing. Ajax response goes into success.